# Overwrite the Express router

Tags: node.js, express

I wanted to create MVC based architecture on the express for that I want to overwrite the Express Router.

Consider following as an example:

```
// usual express router
var userRouter = require('express').Router();    
userRouter.get("/",function(req, res, next){
    //.....
});    
userRouter.post("/",function(req, res, next){
    //.....
});    
app.use('/users', userRouter);    

//routes.js    
module.exports = function(app){
    var userRouter = app.Router();    
    userRouter.get('/', {controller: 'User', action: 'show'});
    userRouter.post('/', {controller: 'User', action: 'new'});    
    app.use('/users', userRouter);
};
```

So, do I have to implement router again like the express with my controller parsing functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting already existing functionality is commonly accepted as bad practice. Express has the option to modify data via middleware services.

If neither the native router, nor the middleware functionality works for you, then maybe you should go and change the framework to Hapi.

I judge my own short experience, Hapi provides better accommodation for routing and server magic.